# What does this lex program do? What is it ECHOing?

Tags: lex

What does the following partial lex program do? What does it output?

```
NW [^A-Za-z']
%start INW NIW

%%

<NIW>"bork"/{NW} ECHO;
<NIW>"Bork"/{NW} ECHO;
```

Comment: Nothing switches to the `NIW` state, so it doesn't match the two actions where you have `ECHO`.

Comment: Echo means you print yytext.

Answer (score 0):

The lexer is incomplete:

- Nothing switches to the NIW state,
- so it doesn't match the two actions where you have ECHO.

That means that

- The *default* rule matches for each input character.
- The default rule for lex does an ECHO.
- Because every input character is echoed, without changes, the output file is the same as the input.